# How to change icon in an array in react typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-typescript

I am trying to create accordion that when you click it will slide down and change the icon

Here is my following code in `App.tsx`:

```
const accordionList = [
  {
    title: "Horses can..."
    icon: "",
    pointer: ""
  },
  {
    title: "Rhino skin maybe.."
    icon: "",
    pointer: ""
  },
  {
    title: "If you looking..."
    icon: "",
    pointer: ""
  }
]

function App() {
  const [icon, setIcon] = useState([''])
  const toggleAccordion = (accordion: any, index: any) => {
    const iconRotate = [...accordion.pointer];
    iconRotate[accordion.pointer] = '';
    setIcon(iconRotate[accordion.pointer])
    accordion.pointer = icon;

  }

  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-header">
        {accordionList.map((accordion, index) => (
          <ul className="accordion-list" key={index}>
            <div className="accordion-item">
              <button onClick={() => toggleAccordion(accordion, index)}>{accordion.icon} {icon} </button>
              <Accordion accordion={accordion} />
            </div>
          </ul>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and here is my following code in `Accordion.tsx`:

```
interface Props {
  accordion: { title: string, icon: string;}
}

export const Accordion: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {

  const { accordion } = props;

  return (
      <div>
        {accordion.title}
      </div>
    )
};
```

Right now my `toggleAccordion` function didn't change the icon when it clicked. How can I improve my function?

Updated pointer to array of objects

Comment: why are you accessing `accordion.pointer` when accordion only have title and icon? I think this should throw you an error when clicking the button right?

Comment: Yess it was throwing me an error but I was error when my array of objects not have pointer. I just updated my current code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of what you're trying to accomplish, to change the icon, you just need to update the `icon` state rather than updating the pointer inside your `accordionList.pointer` and maintain this icon state for all the item in the icon list you have. I'll suggest you to divide your accordion item into its own component with the icon state like below:

The `App.js` file:

```js
const accordionList = [
  {
    title: "Horses can..."
    icon: "",
    pointer: ""
  },
  {
    title: "Rhino skin maybe.."
    icon: "",
    pointer: ""
  },
  {
    title: "If you looking..."
    icon: "",
    pointer: ""
  }
]

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-header">
        {accordionList.map((accordion, index) => (
          <ul className="accordion-list" key={index}>
            <AccordionItem accordion={accordion}/>
          </ul>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The `AccordionItem` component:

```js
function AccordionItem({accordion}) {
  const [indicatorIcon, setIndicatorIcon] = useState('')
  const toggleAccordion = () => {
     setIndicatorIcon('');
  }
  return (
    <div className="accordion-item">
        <button 
         onClick={() => toggleAccordion(accordion, index)}
        >{accordion.icon} {icon} </button>
        <Accordion accordion={accordion} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And you can keep your `Accordion` as is. This will separate your concern, help you to only need to care about the state of the `AccordionItem`, and this will remove any unnecessary complex array manipulation.

Comment: What if you click the button again and the icon will turn back to point left?

Comment: if you want it to turn back, just add another check if the `indicatorIcon` is '' and change back like this `setIndicatorIcon(currentIndicatorIcon => currentIndicatorIcon === ''? '':'')`